# How to make img source url working with ui-router

Tags: angularjs, meteor, angular-ui-router

I have a small page, with only one route, so I define it:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
$stateProvider
            .state('main', {
                url: '/',
                views: {
                    'footer': {
                        templateUrl: baseUrl + 'footer.ng.html'
                    },
                    'header': {
                        templateUrl: baseUrl + 'header.ng.html'
                    },
                    'content': {
                        templateUrl: baseUrl + 'content.ng.html'
                    }
                }
            });
```

The problem is: in html, I have an image `<img ng-src="public/images/xetapdi.jpg" alt="Xe tập đi" />`. This image cannot show. When I try to open image link in chrome, it open full my page. Althrough that is a direct link of image, it does not show an image.

I use angular with meteor. Please help me fix this issue. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't that be `<img ng-src="/images/xetapdi.jpg" alt="Xe tập đi" />`? The `/public` part of the path is not reflected to the site, essentially every directory immediately below `/public` shows up at root.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You save my time.